# Max item per row flexbox layout

Tags: android, flexbox

How to set max item per row in flexbox android? i want `maxItemPerRow=2` and the last line is centered like this :

[image]

Comment: Check this [link](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout) You could use the one that fits your requirement.

Comment: @MdBasha,  you give me so many code? are you sure this is the right way to answer a question?

Comment: Kindly refer Example 13 and Example 14 in that link, Zihad